# webgl glsl shader problem ,the same fragment shader code on windows and macos has a completely different performance

Tags: glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I just started learning webgl GLSL.I recently had a strange problem that almost killed my life.
I wrote a simple cube texture rendering code, and I used the normal vector in the fragment shader to add some special effects. This code basically works the same on Windows as I expected, but it shows me a black screen on macos and ios, and then I tested the Android system, which is as normal as on Windows. I guess there is a difference between the windows platform and the macos platform. There are some secrets I don't know. Are there any good people who are willing to help me, thank you!
Here is the vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
attribute vec3 aNormal;

uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
  vNormal = aNormal;
}
```

This is the fragment shader:

```c
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying  vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
  vec4 an = vec4(vNormal, 1.0);
  gl_FragColor = an * texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
}
```

Here is the windows show:
[windos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYy4y.png)

[image]

Here is the macos show:
[macos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvXWl.png)

[image]

**11/18/2019 Update : Thanks to the friendly advice of @gman, I updated the code.**

```js
var cubeRotation = 0.0;

main();

//
// Start here
//
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#glcanvas');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

  // If we don't have a GL context, give up now

  if (!gl) {
    alert('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.');
    return;
  }

  const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
    attribute vec3 aNormal;

    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;
      vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
      vNormal = aNormal;
    }
  `;

  // Fragment shader program

  const fsSource = `
    precision mediump float;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler;

    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying  vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main(void) {
      vec4 an = vec4(vNormal, 1.0);
      gl_FragColor = an * texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
    }
  `;

  // Initialize a shader program; this is where all the lighting
  // for the vertices and so forth is established.
  const shaderProgram = initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource);

  // Collect all the info needed to use the shader program.
  // Look up which attributes our shader program is using
  // for aVertexPosition, aTextureCoord and also
  // look up uniform locations.
  const programInfo = {
    program: shaderProgram,
    attribLocations: {
      vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexPosition'),
      textureCoord: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aTextureCoord'),
      normal: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aNormal')
    },
    uniformLocations: {
      projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uProjectionMatrix'),
      modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uModelViewMatrix'),
      uSampler: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uSampler'),
    },
  };

  // Here's where we call the routine that builds all the
  // objects we'll be drawing.
  const buffers = initBuffers(gl);

  const texture = loadTexture(gl, 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHbv0.png');

  var then = 0;

  // Draw the scene repeatedly
  function render(now) {
    now *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;

    drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers, texture, deltaTime);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

//
// initBuffers
//
// Initialize the buffers we'll need. For this demo, we just
// have one object -- a simple three-dimensional cube.
//
function initBuffers(gl) {

  // Create a buffer for the cube's vertex positions.

  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Select the positionBuffer as the one to apply buffer
  // operations to from here out.

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Now create an array of positions for the cube.

  const positions = [
    // Front face
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,

    // Back face
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

    // Top face
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0,

    // Bottom face
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,

    // Right face
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,

    // Left face
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
  ];

  // Now pass the list of positions into WebGL to build the
  // shape. We do this by creating a Float32Array from the
  // JavaScript array, then use it to fill the current buffer.

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Now set up the texture coordinates for the faces.

  const textureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBuffer);

  const textureCoordinates = [
    // Front
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    // Back
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    // Top
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    // Bottom
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    // Right
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    // Left
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
  ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoordinates),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW);


  // set up normals 
  const normalsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalsBuffer);

  const normals = [
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normals),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Build the element array buffer; this specifies the indices
  // into the vertex arrays for each face's vertices.

  const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);

  // This array defines each face as two triangles, using the
  // indices into the vertex array to specify each triangle's
  // position.

  const indices = [
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,    // front
    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7,    // back
    8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11,   // top
    12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15,   // bottom
    16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19,   // right
    20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23,   // left
  ];

  // Now send the element array to GL

  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  return {
    position: positionBuffer,
    textureCoord: textureCoordBuffer,
    normals: normalsBuffer,
    indices: indexBuffer,
  };
}

//
// Initialize a texture and load an image.
// When the image finished loading copy it into the texture.
//
function loadTexture(gl, url) {
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Because images have to be download over the internet
  // they might take a moment until they are ready.
  // Until then put a single pixel in the texture so we can
  // use it immediately. When the image has finished downloading
  // we'll update the texture with the contents of the image.
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const width = 1;
  const height = 1;
  const border = 0;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  const pixel = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]);  // opaque blue
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
    width, height, border, srcFormat, srcType,
    pixel);

  const image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = '';
  image.onload = function () {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
      srcFormat, srcType, image);

    // WebGL1 has different requirements for power of 2 images
    // vs non power of 2 images so check if the image is a
    // power of 2 in both dimensions.
    if (isPowerOf2(image.width) && isPowerOf2(image.height)) {
      // Yes, it's a power of 2. Generate mips.
      gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    } else {
      // No, it's not a power of 2. Turn of mips and set
      // wrapping to clamp to edge
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    }
  };
  image.src = url;

  return texture;
}

function isPowerOf2(value) {
  return (value & (value - 1)) == 0;
}

//
// Draw the scene.
//
function drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers, texture, deltaTime) {
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // Clear to black, fully opaque
  gl.clearDepth(1.0);                 // Clear everything
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);           // Enable depth testing
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);            // Near things obscure far things

  // Clear the canvas before we start drawing on it.

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Create a perspective matrix, a special matrix that is
  // used to simulate the distortion of perspective in a camera.
  // Our field of view is 45 degrees, with a width/height
  // ratio that matches the display size of the canvas
  // and we only want to see objects between 0.1 units
  // and 100 units away from the camera.

  const fieldOfView = 45 * Math.PI / 180;   // in radians
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const zNear = 0.1;
  const zFar = 100.0;
  const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();

  // note: glmatrix.js always has the first argument
  // as the destination to receive the result.
  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix,
    fieldOfView,
    aspect,
    zNear,
    zFar);

  // Set the drawing position to the "identity" point, which is
  // the center of the scene.
  const modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();

  // Now move the drawing position a bit to where we want to
  // start drawing the square.

  mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix,     // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix,     // matrix to translate
    [-0.0, 0.0, -6.0]);  // amount to translate
  mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix,  // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix,  // matrix to rotate
    cubeRotation,     // amount to rotate in radians
    [0, 0, 1]);       // axis to rotate around (Z)
  mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix,  // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix,  // matrix to rotate
    cubeRotation * .7,// amount to rotate in radians
    [0, 1, 0]);       // axis to rotate around (X)

  // Tell WebGL how to pull out the positions from the position
  // buffer into the vertexPosition attribute
  {
    const numComponents = 3;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition);
  }

  // Tell WebGL how to pull out the texture coordinates from
  // the texture coordinate buffer into the textureCoord attribute.
  {
    const numComponents = 2;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.textureCoord);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.textureCoord,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(
      programInfo.attribLocations.textureCoord);
  }


  // normal
  {
    const numComponents = 3;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.normals);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.normal,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(
      programInfo.attribLocations.normal);
  }

  // Tell WebGL which indices to use to index the vertices
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.indices);

  // Tell WebGL to use our program when drawing

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  // Set the shader uniforms

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix,
    false,
    projectionMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix,
    false,
    modelViewMatrix);

  // Specify the texture to map onto the faces.

  // Tell WebGL we want to affect texture unit 0
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);

  // Bind the texture to texture unit 0
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Tell the shader we bound the texture to texture unit 0
  gl.uniform1i(programInfo.uniformLocations.uSampler, 0);

  {
    const vertexCount = 36;
    const type = gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexCount, type, offset);
  }

  // Update the rotation for the next draw

  cubeRotation += deltaTime;
}

//
// Initialize a shader program, so WebGL knows how to draw our data
//
function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
  const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
  const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);

  // Create the shader program

  const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

  // If creating the shader program failed, alert

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    return null;
  }

  return shaderProgram;
}

//
// creates a shader of the given type, uploads the source and
// compiles it.
//
function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);

  // Send the source to the shader object

  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);

  // Compile the shader program

  gl.compileShader(shader);

  // See if it compiled successfully

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
    return null;
  }

  return shader;
}
```

```css
canvas {
      border: 2px solid black;
      background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WebGL Demo</title>
  <script src="https://mdn.github.io/webgl-examples/tutorial/gl-matrix.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
</body>


</html>
```

**Solution:
current the normal vector to this solved my problem:**

```
  const normals = [
0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
0.0, 0.0, -1.0,

0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0, 0.0,


0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
0.0, -1.0, 0.0,

1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
1.0, 0.0, 0.0,


-1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
```

];

Comment: And what sort of errors are you getting back from GL? What does your profiler or frame debugger say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post more code!

The only possibility to that comes to mind is that if you guessed the attribute locations instead of looking them up then maybe you guessed correctly on your GPU on Windows but that guess didn't work on MacOS or iOS.

You can't guess attiribute locations. You have to look them up or assign them.

Trying your shaders myself they work just fine.

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const vs = `
attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
attribute vec3 aNormal;

uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
  vNormal = aNormal;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying  vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
  vec4 an = vec4(vNormal, 1.0);
  gl_FragColor = an * texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
}
`;

// compile shaders, link program, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const arrays = twgl.primitives.createCubeVertices(1);
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData
// for each array
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  aVertexPosition: arrays.position,
  aTextureCoord: arrays.texcoord,
  aNormal: arrays.normal,
  indices: arrays.indices,
});

// creates a 2x2 texture
const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: new Uint8Array([
    255, 128, 128, 255,
    128, 255, 128, 255,
    128, 128, 255, 255,
    255, 128, 255, 255,
  ]),
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;

  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  // for each attribute
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

  const uProjectionMatrix = m4.perspective(
      Math.PI * 0.25, 
      gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight,
      0.1,
      10);

  const uModelViewMatrix = m4.identity();
  m4.translate(uModelViewMatrix, [0, 0, -2], uModelViewMatrix);
  m4.rotateX(uModelViewMatrix, time, uModelViewMatrix);
  m4.rotateY(uModelViewMatrix, time, uModelViewMatrix);

  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    uProjectionMatrix,
    uModelViewMatrix,
    uSampler: tex,
  });

  // calls either gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Note: I used twgl because your question wasn't asking how to do webgl (which is too big a question). Your question was effectively "why don't my shaders work on MacOS/iOS" and the code above proves they work just fine.

[image]

Suggest you try [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org)

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const vs = `
attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
attribute vec3 aNormal;

uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
  vNormal = aNormal;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying  vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
  vec4 an = vec4(vNormal, 1.0);
  gl_FragColor = an * texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
}
`;

// compile shaders, link program
const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
const aVertexPositionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aVertexPosition');
const aTextureCoordLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aTextureCoord');
const aNormalLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aNormal');
const uProjectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uProjectionMatrix');
const uModelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uModelViewMatrix');
const uSamplerLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uSampler');

const arrays = twgl.primitives.createCubeVertices(1);
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData
// for each array
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  aVertexPosition: arrays.position,
  aTextureCoord: arrays.texcoord,
  aNormal: arrays.normal,
  indices: arrays.indices,
});

// creates a 2x2 texture
const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: new Uint8Array([
    255, 128, 128, 255,
    128, 255, 128, 255,
    128, 128, 255, 255,
    255, 128, 255, 255,
  ]),
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;

  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  
  gl.useProgram(program);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aVertexPositionLoc);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfo.attribs.aVertexPosition.buffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPositionLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aTextureCoordLoc);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfo.attribs.aTextureCoord.buffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(aTextureCoordLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aNormalLoc);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfo.attribs.aNormal.buffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(aNormalLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfo.indices);

  const uProjectionMatrix = m4.perspective(
      Math.PI * 0.25, 
      gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight,
      0.1,
      10);

  const uModelViewMatrix = m4.identity();
  m4.translate(uModelViewMatrix, [0, 0, -2], uModelViewMatrix);
  m4.rotateX(uModelViewMatrix, time, uModelViewMatrix);
  m4.rotateY(uModelViewMatrix, time, uModelViewMatrix);

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.uniform1i(uSamplerLoc, 0);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uProjectionMatrixLoc, false, uProjectionMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uModelViewMatrixLoc, false, uModelViewMatrix);

  gl.drawElements(
      gl.TRIANGLES,
      bufferInfo.numElements,
      bufferInfo.elementType,
      0);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: problem solved!,  it's exactly like what you said : "The only possibility to that comes to mind is that if you guessed the attribute locations instead of looking them up then maybe you guessed correctly on your GPU on Windows but that guess didn't work on MacOS or iOS." thanks!,  my normals vector array data  is  wrong. The strange thing is that the browser on ios does not have any warnings and errors.